# window.opener | not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am having two html pages..i am calling parent window from child..All things works great.but in Chrome it fails..let me know the reason..

test1.html :-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Compose</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<SCRIPT>
function test(){
//alert('');
var win = window.open('../login/test2.html',"","height=700,width=800");
}
function test1(){
alert('test1');
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="click" onclick="test();" />             
</body>
</html>
```

test2.html :-

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<SCRIPT>
function opener1(){
try{
    if(window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed)
    {

    }
    window.opener.test1();
    }catch(e){ alert(e.description);}
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false"  ondragstart="return false" onload="opener1();">
<h1>Test Page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Calling method in test1.html from test2.html not working..any solutions..appreciated..thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the parent window can only be accessed using the `parent` variable.
The following modification to opener1 function should make this possible

```
function opener1(){
    try{
        if(parent.window.opener != null && !parent.window.opener.closed)
        {
          parent.window.opener.test1();
        }

    }catch(e){ alert(e.description);}       
}
```

Comment: Why is a `parent` involved in this?

Comment: hi anurpur still the same pblm..alert says undefined

Comment: because you want to access the function of the window(test1.html) from which the second window(test2.html) is called. so test1.html is the parent window of test2.html. this is how javascript operates. simply calling window refers to the current window.

Comment: if the alert says undefined , the alert in the catch block would be called. can you paste the error that is shown in the console?

Comment: interesting..it seems to be fine on this end. are you 100% sure that you made the change to the opener1 function in test2.html?

Comment: can you paste the code for the modified test2.html please? just for verification purposes

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<SCRIPT>
function opener1(){
try{
 if(parent.window.opener != null && !parent.window.opener.closed)
 {
    
 }
 parent.window.opener.test1();
 }catch(e){ alert(e.description);}
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false"  ondragstart="return false" onload="opener1();">
<h1>Test Page</h1>

</body>
</html>

Comment: error msg is :blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross origin frame

Comment: are you running test2.html before running test1.html?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47150/discussion-between-sree-and-anurupr)

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be fine for me. If you catch an exception you can log it to console to get information of what is wrong. Make sure domains of test1.html and test2.html match, otherwise you will get security exception.

Comment: error msg is :blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross origin frame

Comment: So this means that domains does not match of your parent-child windows. Also this will not work if html opened from file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code:

```
window.opener.document.location.href = url;
```

This will work both IE and Chrome.

```
window.opener.location.href = 'test.html';
```

This would open the page "test.html".

and you can close the parent window once its opened.

Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if its works.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the `opener` property of `windows` object is null on devices like **iPad** or **Chrome**.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 64 under Windows 7 and "window.opener" is not null at all.

Comment: @Elo It is null for me.