# window.opener not working on chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, window.opener

tried the accepted answer of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671218/window-opener-not-working-in-chrome)
used top.window.opener to access the parent.html .no luck . below is my code

parentWindow.html

```
<p>Click the button to write some text to the source (parent) window.</p>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>

<script>
function test1()
{
    alert("test1");
}
function openWin()
{
var myWindow = window.open("childWindow.html");

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

childWindow.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <title>Child</title>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">

function Initialize()
{
     try{
        if(top.window.opener != null && !top.window.opener.closed)
        {
          top.window.opener.test1();
        }

    }catch(e){ alert(e.description);}  


}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="Initialize()">

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Same code tried on server after following the excerpts from [this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/KXWxXF6RJZY).
Dint help.

Comment: Where do you have the `parent` keyword from the link you provided, and why are you using `top` instead?

Comment: used both parent keyword and top . no luck @TomasPastircak

Comment: Have you refreshed the page completely via Ctrl+F5? It may had the incorrect variant cached.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standards, the second parameter should default to `_blank` if it is omitted, but all browsers might not follow that. Specify the target so that you know that it really opens in a new window and doesn't replace the current window:

```
window.open("childWindow.html", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you would like to do is `parent.window.opener`:

```
    if(parent.window.opener != null && ! parent.window.opener)
    {
      parent.window.opener.test1();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Frames has a parent window, not separate windows.

Comment: @Guffa, Thank you for your helpful comment. But I don't understand which `Frames` you mentioned. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: If the page is inside a `frame` or `iframe` in a page, then it has a parent window. If it's opened as a new window, then it has no parent.

Comment: @Guffa, Thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean. Actually in case the page is inside frames, the page has a parent.

Comment: @Guffa,Thank you again. I afraid I might not understand what you exactly  mean. Could you point me to the right direction?  I would like to learn a case where the page has no parent.

Comment: A window only has a parent if it is opened in a frame or an iframe. If you use `window.open` the page has no parent, unless you specifically open it in a frame or an iframe that already exist.

Comment: @Guffa, Thank you for your kind answer. I think I can understand what you mean. Could you check this sample which I wrote just now ? http://swift-exploder-php-36-103575.apne1.nitrousbox.com/parent.html   I use parent.window.opener.test1(); in child.html.

Comment: Yes, that won't work as the window that you open doesn't have any parent. Besides, the use of Javascript in the `href` attribute makes the opener page be replaced by the text representation of the window object of the window that you open.

Comment: @Guffa, I'm sorry for asking you many times, but it seems that the script which I wrote above works on my chrome browser. What is possiblely wrong with me?

Comment: I don't know why it works in Chrome. I then tried it in Internet Explorer and Firefox, and it work in neither of those, just as expected.