# Why Can't I have access to the opener window in Chrome ? (Ok with IE)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open, window.opener

window.opener doesn't work in Chrome. Ok for IE. Do you know why ?
Is it a problme of cross-document interactions ? I don't know why, files are in the same folder on my local computer.

I want the child window could access to the datas (DOM for exemple) of the parent window and modify them.

This is a example :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parent Window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="data" value="1234567" />
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openChildWindow();">Open Child Popup window</a>
  <script>
    function openChildWindow() {
      window.open('child.html','childWindow','width=400,height=400');
    }
  </script>
 </body>
```

And for the cild window child.html :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Child Window</title>
      <script>
        function initializeMainDiv() {  
          document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = "Parent window data field value is: " +
          window.opener.document.getElementById("data").value
        }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="initializeMainDiv();">
      <div id="mainDiv"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work on my chrome. I don't understand why, the code is simple.

I try with parent.window.openener, but the result is the same.

Comment: You could use localStorage to share data between browser tabs/windows. It seems to have better browser support than window.opener. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: ok, I see for localStorage. But in fact, I want the Dom of the opener window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.opener | not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671218/window-opener-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: the solution doesn't work in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671218/window-opener-not-working-in-chrome](window.opener | not working in chrome)